# update TListView item

Tags: delphi, listview

I want to update values in a TListView. I tryed this

```
...
lvProcess : TListView;
liEdit : TlistItem;
...
   liEdit:=lvProcess.Items.Item[1];
   liEdit.Caption:='11';
   liEdit.SubItems.ValueFromIndex[0]:='22';
   liEdit.SubItems.ValueFromIndex[1]:='33';
...
```

this should do what I want, but after this, the values of the subitems are this ones '=22' and '=33'
I don't want the equal character to be added.

Can anyone help me? I don't know if this is the right way to edit/update a listitem

thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293112/how-to-change-a-subitem-in-a-listview - please search SO before you ask a new question.

Comment: @mghie: Despite the similarity, this is not a duplicate of the question you linked.

Comment: You have an example of what you're supposed to do; I'll explain what went wrong. One of the features of TStringList (_SubItems is a TStringList_) is that it can store `name=value` pairs. Your code set the **value** of each of the first two strings. There was no name for each of the strings so effectively you stored `=value`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the following :

```
with LvProcess.Items[1] do
begin
  Caption := '11';
  SubItems.Strings[0] := '22';
  SubItems.Strings[1] := '33';
end;
```

And if you're updating many items at once it is better to surround the update in a way like this:

```
try
  lvProcess.Items.BeginUpdate;

  //Do your updates
finally
  lvProcess.Items.EndUpdate;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

SubItems is a TStrings, so if you want to update the string values, do so like this:

```
SubItems[0] := '22'
SubItems[1] := '33'
```

The way you're doing it now, you're using the TStrings as Key/Value list.  That's a nice feature of TStrings when you want it, but probably not what you intend.